# Jquery and AJAX post to php data attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello I have the following AJAX code:

```
 var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: 'saveImage.php',  //Server script to process data
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);            
    }

});
```

It works great and it loads up the PHP page it the background like it should:

```
    <?php
        include_once "mysql_connect.php";
        $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["Image1"]["name"]);
        $imageData = '';
        $imageext = '';
        if($imageName != null){
            $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["Image1"]["tmp_name"]));
            $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["Image1"]["type"]);
            $imageSize = getimagesize($_FILES["Image1"]["tmp_name"]);
            $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["Image1"]["type"]);
            $FileSize = FileSize($_FILES["Image1"]["tmp_name"]);
            $imageext = mysql_real_escape_string($imageSize['mime']);
        }
        $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO pictures (`id`, `imagedata`, `imageext`) VALUES ('', '$imageData', '$imageext');"); 


        echo $imageext;


?>
```

The only problem is that the PHP page cant find the variable Image1 which is the name of the input in the form. Have I done something wrong. I was thinking that maybe in the data parameter in the Ajax it would be something like this but correct:

```
data: "Image1"=formData,
```

Is that a thing, if not why cant my PHP see that input field?

Comment: Can we see your HTML form?

Comment: As a debugging step, try adding `print_r($_POST);` and `print_r($_FILES);` to you PHP so you can see exactly what what data is being sent and what names are being used.

Comment: @Joe it gives me <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Image1 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\website\saveImage.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
Array
(
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot cache and contentType properties in your Ajax function. Try that it should work :

```
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",                
   url: "saveImage.php",
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   cache:false,
   data: formData,
   success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```